# Scaling iOS CIDetector (face detection) coordinates from aspectRatioThumbnail to fullScreenImage

Tags: ios, core-image

*(ignore the massive block of code below. It's just there for reference/resource in case anyone else wants to play along)*

The face detection routines in CoreImage naturally work faster on smaller images so I have been investigating using the `aspectRatioThumbnail` to generate the face data with the plan to scale it up to draw on the `fullScreenImage` representation. The reason I am doing this is that I have potentially 20-30 images to process so I want to reduce the task time.

This may be a simple math problem but I am getting inaccurate results trying to map a point in one image to another.

90 x 120 image - CGPoint(64, 50) rightEyePosition

to

480 x 640 image - CGPoint(331, 303) rightEyePosition

**(480 /90) * 64 = 341.333** - but it should be 331, yes? Am I doing it wrong?

**Update** - a few more tests later. So perhaps it is just that the face data result varies slightly because of the different image resolutions? That would make sense: that there is not a scalable relationship between data results. I still wonder though: *is my scaling math wrong above?*

---

```
Using CIDetectorAccuracyHigh     
useImageOptions:     0
------------ aspectRatioThumbnail   90.000000  120.000000 orientation: 0
2013-01-18 12:33:30.378 SeqMeTestBed[9705:907] aspectRatioThumbnail: features {
    bounds = "{{23, 16}, {56, 56}}";
    hasLeftEyePosition = 1;
    hasMouthPosition = 1;
    hasRightEyePosition = 1;
    leftEyePosition = "{43, 59}";
    mouthPosition = "{51, 31}";
    rightEyePosition = "{64, 50}";
}
------------ fullScreenImage   480.000000  640.000000 orientation: 0
2013-01-18 12:33:33.029 SeqMeTestBed[9705:907] fullScreenImage: features {
    bounds = "{{135, 81}, {298, 298}}";
    hasLeftEyePosition = 1;
    hasMouthPosition = 1;
    hasRightEyePosition = 1;
    leftEyePosition = "{228, 321}";
    mouthPosition = "{290, 156}";
    rightEyePosition = "{331, 303}";
}
------------ fullResolutionImage   640.000000  480.000000 orientation: 0
2013-01-18 12:33:35.745 SeqMeTestBed[9705:907] fullResolutionImage: features {
    bounds = "{{195, 105}, {366, 366}}";
    hasLeftEyePosition = 1;
    hasMouthPosition = 1;
    hasRightEyePosition = 1;
    leftEyePosition = "{356, 411}";
    mouthPosition = "{350, 201}";
    rightEyePosition = "{455, 400}";
```

// code used
//

```
- (void)detectFacialFeatures
{

    NSDictionary *detectorOptions = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh, CIDetectorAccuracy, nil];
    CIDetector* faceDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:detectorOptions];


    NSDictionary *imageOptions = nil;

    UIImage *tmpImage;
    NSNumber* orientation; 
    CIImage *ciImage;
    NSArray *array;
    NSMutableDictionary* featuresDictionary;

    Boolean useImageOptions = NO;

    printf("Using CIDetectorAccuracyHigh     \n");
    printf("useImageOptions:     %d\n", useImageOptions);

    //-----------------aspectRatioThumbnail
    tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:self.asset.aspectRatioThumbnail];
    orientation = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tmpImage.imageOrientation];

    printf("------------ aspectRatioThumbnail   %f  %f orientation: %d\n", tmpImage.size.width, tmpImage.size.height, [orientation integerValue]);
    ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:tmpImage.CGImage];
    if (ciImage == nil) printf("----------!!!aspectRatioThumbnail: ciImage is nil    \n");

    imageOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:orientation, CIDetectorImageOrientation,
                    CIDetectorAccuracyHigh, CIDetectorAccuracy, nil];

    if (useImageOptions) {
        array = [faceDetector featuresInImage:ciImage];
    } else {
        array = [faceDetector featuresInImage:ciImage options:imageOptions];
    }

    featuresDictionary = [self convertFeaturesToDictionary:array];
    NSLog(@"aspectRatioThumbnail: features %@", featuresDictionary);

   //-----------------fullScreenImage
    tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:self.asset.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage];
    orientation = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tmpImage.imageOrientation];
    printf("------------ fullScreenImage   %f  %f orientation: %d\n", tmpImage.size.width, tmpImage.size.height, [orientation integerValue]);

    ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:tmpImage.CGImage];
    if (ciImage == nil) printf("----------!!!fullScreenImage: ciImage is nil    \n");

    imageOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:orientation, CIDetectorImageOrientation,
                    CIDetectorAccuracyHigh, CIDetectorAccuracy, nil];

    if (useImageOptions) {
        array = [faceDetector featuresInImage:ciImage];
    } else {
        array = [faceDetector featuresInImage:ciImage options:imageOptions];
    }

    featuresDictionary = [self convertFeaturesToDictionary:array];
    NSLog(@"fullScreenImage: features %@", featuresDictionary);

    //-----------------fullResolutionImage
    tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:self.asset.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage];
    orientation = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tmpImage.imageOrientation];

    printf("------------ fullResolutionImage   %f  %f orientation: %d\n", tmpImage.size.width, tmpImage.size.height, [orientation integerValue]);

    ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:tmpImage.CGImage];
    if (ciImage == nil) printf("----------!!!fullResolutionImage: ciImage is nil    \n");

    imageOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:orientation, CIDetectorImageOrientation,
                    CIDetectorAccuracyHigh, CIDetectorAccuracy, nil];

    if (useImageOptions) {
        array = [faceDetector featuresInImage:ciImage];
    } else {
        array = [faceDetector featuresInImage:ciImage options:imageOptions];
    }

    featuresDictionary = [self convertFeaturesToDictionary:array];
    NSLog(@"fullResolutionImage: features %@", featuresDictionary);

}







- (NSMutableDictionary*)convertFeaturesToDictionary:(NSArray*)foundFaces
{
    NSMutableDictionary * faceFeatures = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if (foundFaces.count) {

        CIFaceFeature *face = [foundFaces objectAtIndex:0];
        NSNumber* hasMouthPosition = [NSNumber numberWithBool:face.hasMouthPosition];
        NSNumber* hasLeftEyePosition = [NSNumber numberWithBool:face.hasLeftEyePosition];
        NSNumber* hasRightEyePosition = [NSNumber numberWithBool:face.hasRightEyePosition];

        [faceFeatures setValue:hasMouthPosition forKey:@"hasMouthPosition"];
        [faceFeatures setValue:hasLeftEyePosition forKey:@"hasLeftEyePosition"];
        [faceFeatures setValue:hasRightEyePosition forKey:@"hasRightEyePosition"];

        NSString * boundRect = NSStringFromCGRect(face.bounds);
       // NSLog(@"------------boundRect %@", boundRect);
        [faceFeatures setValue:boundRect forKey:@"bounds"];

        if (hasMouthPosition){
            NSString * mouthPosition = NSStringFromCGPoint(face.mouthPosition);
            [faceFeatures setValue:mouthPosition forKey:@"mouthPosition"];
        }

        if (hasLeftEyePosition){
            NSString * leftEyePosition = NSStringFromCGPoint(face.leftEyePosition);
            [faceFeatures setValue:leftEyePosition forKey:@"leftEyePosition"];
        }

        if (hasRightEyePosition){
            NSString * rightEyePosition = NSStringFromCGPoint(face.rightEyePosition);
            [faceFeatures setValue:rightEyePosition forKey:@"rightEyePosition"];
        }

    }
    return faceFeatures;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your math is correct based on the assumption that the thumbnail image retains all the facial data required for detection.

That assumption does not hold since in a thumbnail image it is harder, even for a human, to recognize a face.

Thus, with the higher resolution image the engine should return a more accurate face location that should be more tightly bound to the actual face. By simply scaling the values from the thumbnail image, it should still generally match to the detected face but you should definitely expect lower accuracy.